# how to query duplicated records of many column?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to query duplicated records and the primary key of the table is more than 3 columns.

I write it as follow:

```
   SELECT * FROM table1 t 
   where (t.col1,t.col2,t.col3) in
   (
    SELECT col1,col2,col3 from table1  
    GROUP BY col1,col2,col3 
    HAVING count(*)>1
   )
```

but it doesn't work in sql server 2008.and it reports a wrong code.
then please tell me how to write the right one sql statement.
thanks.

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results and query what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you provided a demo sample, you can use this for example:

```
-- Create demo data
CREATE TABLE #temp(col1 int, col2 int, col3 int)

INSERT INTO #temp(col1, col2, col3)
VALUES  (1,1,1),(1,2,3),(1,2,4),
        (1,2,3)-- the duplicate one

-- only the duplicated rows
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM #temp
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

-- Get all columns back based on the duplicates
SELECT *
FROM #temp as t
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT col1, col2, col3
        FROM #temp
        GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) as dubs
    ON t.col1 = dubs.col1
    AND t.col2 = dubs.col2
    AND t.col3 = dubs.col3

-- Cleanup
DROP TABLE #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out! This is the case where you want to check the duplicate in three columns. If the query does not return any result that means there are no duplicates else the count(*) column count explains the number of duplicates for each combination. Please try adding the columns which you have the key on in the place of col1, col2 and col3.

SELECT col1,col2,col3,count(*) from table1

GROUP BY col1,col2,col3 
HAVING count(*)>1

Hope this helps!